# Finding information stored in array by binary search

Tags: java, class, search, binary

This is a small library with two books for the sake of the question, it allows the user to type in a random number, and if that number matches up with a book the title of the book is outputted. I've created a class called 'Book' which houses all the titles.

String book1, book2;

```
    class Book {

        Book (int _input, String book_1, String book_2) {
            book1 = book_1 = "Read This Book";
            book2 = book_2 = "How to Read a Book";
```

I apologize if my code is all one big mess that makes no sense...

```
        }
    }

ArrayList <Book> titles = new ArrayList <Book>(50);


public static Boolean binarySearch(String [] A, int left, int right, String V) { //binary search
        int middle;
        Boolean found = false;

        while (found == false && left <= right) {
            //If middle item == 0, returns true
            middle = (left + right)/2;
            int compare = A[middle].compareTo(V);
            if (compare == 0) {
                found = true;
            } else {
                if (compare >0) {
                    right = middle -1;
                } else {
                    left = middle + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (left > right) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Then the problem...I'm not sure how to use the binary search to actually output any information after pressing the "find" button, any ideas on what I should below to make this work?

```
private void findButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        //Take inputted values which will match with book title
        int input = Integer.parseInt(enterNumberField.getText());

        //Store values in array
        Book c = new Book (input, book1, book2);
        titles.add(c);

        String temp;

        //calls out information in array
        for (int j=0; j<=input; j++) {
            for (int x=0; x<=input; x++) {
            temp = titles.get(x) + "\n";
            }
            binarySearchField.setText("" + j); //should output book title
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your binary search to return not just a true or false.  You want it to return `Book`, the item it found, or `null` if it found no book matching this query. To be consistent you probably want to change the name from binarySearch, to getBook, or some other better suited name.  In your case you don't want to know if an element is there, you want to get the element for use later (printing).

This is how collections are expected to behave when you query them.  Just check out the get methods from any of the Java collections and you will see they do the same, returning the item if it's there, or null.

Here is some example code. This is just example code! So modify as you like, and also be careful about bugs, I used your search which I'm going to assume is correct to start with.  Also know that there are better many good ways of storing a key to a value, Map for example, that I'm not going to use here.

```
public class Book{
    public String title;
    public int sameTitle(String bookTitle) {
        return this.title.compareTo(bookTitle);
    }
}

public static Book getBook(Book [] A, int left, int right, String bookTitle) { //binary search
    int middle;

    while (left <= right) {
        //If middle item == 0, returns true
        middle = (left + right)/2;
        int compare = A[middle].sameTitle(bookTitle);
        if (compare == 0) {
            return A[middle];
        } else {
            if (compare >0) {
                right = middle -1;
            } else {
                left = middle + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// example use of getting and using the book
Book b = getBook(...);
if (b != null){
    System.out.println("Success! you found the book " + b);
}
```

Comment: The totally sent a light off in my head and that makes a lot of sense, however can I merely replace 'false' or 'true' within my public static binarySearch with 'Book'? Since when I attempt to do so it becomes red underlined, may you please clarify a bit more?

Comment: I've modified my answer to clarify a bit more.  You can't just replace false with true, but you do a few minor changes like change found to Book from a boolean.  Or you can do what I do in my answer and return the book directly

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
int compare = A[middle].compareTo(V);
if (compare == 0) {
    found = true;
```

To:

```
int compare = A[middle].compareTo(V);
if (compare == 0) {
    return A[middle];
```

And be sure to get the result in your `findButtonActionPerformed` method.

Also, it appears to be a mistake in your code... Should not `A` be a book array instead of  a string array?